# Empty parenthesis regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list

```
list1 = ['main()','("%d",b);']
```

I just want empty parenthesis which is main() in output.
But re.compile only showing (%d) in output

```
regex1 = re.compile("[()]")
newlist1 = list(filter(regex1.match, list1))
print(newlist1)
```

Output:

```
['("%d",b);']
```

I want:

```
['main()']
```

Comment: Try `regex1 = re.compile(r"\(\)")`

Comment: And use "search" instead of "match". Otherwise the left parenthesis has to be at the beginning of the string.

Comment: You don't need a regular expression for this.  `newlist1 = [s for s in list1 if '()' in s]`.

Comment: Thanks Michael Butscher for your responsere.compile(r"\(\)") showing whole list in output.

Comment: Thanks Tim Roberts for your solution but I want to solve it with regular expression if it's possible

Comment: @Noob This isn't what I wrote.

Comment: Here you go. Regex is fine here. Escaping is crazy.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
list1 = ['main()','("%d",b);']
regex1 = re.compile(r"\(\)")
newlist1 = list(filter(regex1.search, list1))
print(newlist1)
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##NctNCsIwEEDhfU4RApIZCIXiUjyJddHW0Q7kj@mAevqUKl29xeOrX11KPrfGqRZRK2Qir9rbq735NHIG9MGDOz1cmPDi70boRZ/9C3VzSZUjgbgBBnRoMr0PvheeHJUE/qZbaZR5Cb/VI5oqnBUOg61t).